# Check if string is present in a column only where the preceding cell contains X?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, flatten, textjoin

I'm trying to find out if an individual's has been scheduled in order for another sheet to reference that fact.

The name sheet:

[image: schedule spreadsheet]

The other sheet looks something like this:

[image: Second spreaddsheet]

So 'x' show's up for AM if 'Brooke' is scheduled in the AM for that day. But not for the PM if she hasn't been scheduled for the PM yet (in this case she has been, but this is just an example).

Is there a way to do something like check if a string is present in a column only for rows where the preceding cell is a string 'x'? It would need to also take into account merged cells as well.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: The sheet is not mine to share, unfortunately.

Comment: @player0, what information do you need?

Comment: the whole layout of the sheet. could be a fake dataset - it doesn't matter... can you set up some sample sheet?

Comment: @player0 here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zssoMnY3ci9ZrjnpdKa5cXCQZHx8hENVZ1VaEiwdMj4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(IF(B40:B="",,
 VLOOKUP(ROW(A40:A),  IF(A40:A<>"",  {ROW(A40:A),  A40:A}),  2, 1)&"×"&
 B40:B), QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B5:H37="",,B5:H37&"×"&
 VLOOKUP(ROW(A5:A37), IF(A5:A37<>"", {ROW(A5:A37), A5:A37}), 2, 1)&"♦"&
 COLUMN(B4:H4)-1)), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 matches '.*AM|.*PM' group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 SEQUENCE(1, 7)+1, 0), 1, "X")&"", "\d+", "ERROR")))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10-mIFfKeT_klNSJnn7pEup5Xp4hbQFQEyr29gryYAyA/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I will test this out a bit and mark it as answered when I'm sure it's resolved.

Comment: Hey, so it works well in this context. But I'd be lying if I could say I understood what it is doing. Is there any way you could walk me through it so I could make any future alterations if need be?

Comment: @dedles sure. see full explanation here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10-mIFfKeT_klNSJnn7pEup5Xp4hbQFQEyr29gryYAyA/edit#gid=283704417